# how do I display stars in multiple lines

Tags: javascript

here is a small script in python.

```
for i in range(x):
    print("*"*x)
```

in fact for x=2 for example it displays on line 1 2 stars and 2 stars on line 2.
how to write in javascript?
here is what I programmed (but it only displays 2 stars on line 1 for x=2)

```js
for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  console.log('*' * x);
}
```

who can help me please?

Comment: You left out your JavaScript version.

Comment: Take a look at [`String.prototype.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

Comment: Where do you define `x` in the JavaScript?

Comment: `'*'.repeat(x)`

Comment: i did it but it only displays 2 stars on line 1 for x=2

Comment: What's wrong with that? Isn't that what the Python code does?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (let i = 0; i < x; i++){
   console.log('*'.repeat(i));
}
```